# How to install an NPM plugin using react-scripts

Tags: reactjs, react-scripts, eslint-plugin-react-hooks

I am trying to install and use the [eslint-plugin-react-hooks](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-plugin-react-hooks) plugin in a project. Usually I'd simply run npm install or yarn add but the directions say to use react-scripts because I'm using create-react-app. How do I do that? Do I add a script and list it as a dependency on the package.json file or is there some other way?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: It should work? What is the exact error?

Comment: I think that maybe I'm just misreading the directions.

"Note: If you're using Create React App, please use react-scripts >= 3 instead of adding it directly."

Does that mean that if I use react-scripts >=3 then this plugin is included? I don't have to install anything?

Comment: I can't really rmb the exact specifications of CRA react-scripts, but I have used both react-scripts and eslint-hooks plugin without any issues. All I did is to run `npm i -D` or `yarn add -D` that plugin and configure it on my eslint.js file. Works without issues. Have you tried it?

Comment: @wentjun Not sure are you are spreading the wrong info. CRA react project doesn't have eslint.js. Did you read the question before posting the comment?

Comment: @AtulGupta I added the eslint configuration file on my own. It is not part of CRA.